# Are there brick structures mentioned in the Tanach?

Tags: sources-mekorot, parashat-noach

Besides the Tower of Babylon, are there other brick structures mentioned in the Tanach?

Comment: Would you consider accepting my answer?

Answer (score 3):

The [Sefer haYashar](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaYashar_(midrash)%2C_Book_of_Exodus.16?vhe=Sefer_HaYashar,_Livorno_1870&lang=bi) seems to imply that [Pitom and Raamses](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0201.htm#11) were actually built using Jewish-made bricks:

> ויבנו בני ישראל את פיתום ואת רעמסס, ויעשו את המלאכה כל בני ישראל מהם לובנים לבנים ומהם בונים.‏
>
> And the children of Israel built Pitom and Raamses, and all the children of Israel did the work, part of them making bricks, part of them building.

[Isaiah 65:3](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1065.htm#3) also talks about incense altars made of bricks:

> הָעָ֗ם הַמַּכְעִסִ֥ים אֹתִ֛י עַל־פָּנַ֖י תָּמִ֑יד זֹֽבְחִים֙ בַּגַּנּ֔וֹת וּֽמְקַטְּרִ֖ים עַל־הַלְּבֵנִֽים׃
>
> A people that provoke Me to My face continually, that sacrifice in gardens, and burn incense upon bricks.

[Radak](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.65.3?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Radak&lang2=en) comments that while they were burning out the bricks, idolaters put incense on it:

> **על הלבנים.** בשעה שהיו שורפין הלבנים היו משימין עליהם קטרת לעכו"ם.‏

Comment: Thank you I upvoted it. To accept it, you should explicitly state that no brick structure is mentioned in the whole Tanach. You brought fine interpretations, while the question was about the plain text of the scriptures.

Comment: @Al I don't really get your point. These are all brick structures in my answer. Or do you mean brick buildings? Please clarify.

Comment: Isaiah does not speak of bricks but titles (see there), Radak and Sefer Hayashar are interpretations.